# Windows Server 2008 and Directory Symlinks

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, ntfs, symlink

I have a shared Directory on my TeamCity Server, C:\Work which is about 9 GB and I want to move it to a separate Disk E:.  When I copy the C:\Work to E:\Work and do mklink /D to make a symlink, the target folder is shared but the link does not appear to be shared.  I simply want to delete C:\Work and create a symlink at C:\ that directs to E:\Work so that I may clear some space on the C:\ drive.  It is important that the share still appears to be at C:\ since programs depend on it.  What is the best practice here?

Comment: `What is the best practice here?` To not have applications depending on a share on someone's workstation.

Comment: It is not a workstation, it is a Windows Server dedicated application build server for the TeamCity application. The shared C:\build directory is a requirement of the build agent I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd use a directory mounted volume. That would make C:\Work it's own volume, and not dependent upon the boot volume for providing space. It's more reliable than a symlink, and preserves the wince-worthy dependency you're working around.

Comment: OK, I am trying your suggestion.  I renamed C:\Work to C:\Work_Original, I created a New Folder C:\Work and mounted E:\ to that folder.  I then copied the contents of the original folder to the new mounted folder and set sharing and permissions to be what they were on the original folder.  Does that seem like it should work and be transparent to programs looking for this folder?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal That's exactly what I meant. It should Just Work.